# Can we access tomcat manger from different port from which our web applications are hosted?

Tags: tomcat7

I have tomcat installed on my windows server 2008 R2 on port 8080, I have installed my web services on it,the path of my web application is something like this
  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/mywebservice

now to access my tomcat I need to write xx.xx.xx.xx:8080

Is it possible by changing some configuration file so that my web service would run normal on port 8080 as In url i have mentioned above and I can access my tomcat from different port, other than 8080

for example xx.xx.xx.xx:1891

I don't want to install another tomcat, I don't want to go for any reverse proxy solution

Comment: U run the web-service on the same tomcat itself ?

Comment: Yes I am running web-service on same tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying the web-service on the same tomcat , then the default port of the web-service will be 8080 itself .

Comment: I know default port will be 8080, but can I change it for tomcat manager and run my web services on 8080

Comment: Then I'm afraid that it cannot be accessed from any other port than the hosted port of tomcat

Comment: I need some more suggestions in favor of it.